# How to resolve memory issue while using scrollViewer Windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am developing an app for WP8 in which data is coming from server(Cloud) And want to show huge data in scroll viewer it's working fine only the problem is crashes after some time due to memory problem I have checked in performance tool it exceed memory limit more than 150 MB in scroll viewer I am showing Images which comes from server please give me idea how can I get rid off this problem if someone else face problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you use huge amount of data you can use Incremental loading

check this  :

[Windows 8 Series – Incremental Loading](http://rahulpnath.wordpress.com/2012/10/28/windows-8-series-incremental-loading/)

Comment: I am loading data after checking offset it's working but while I am scrolling above it loaded previous images that's why memory is not reduces give me idea to clean previous memory.

Comment: one of method which i found is to remove images from it's container then set image object to null